# $A$ knights, $B$ priests sitting at round table, expected number of priests sitting directly next to $2$ knights?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

> There are $A$ knights and $B$ priests sitting at a round table, randomly arranged. What is the expected number of priests sitting directly next to $2$ knights?

Here's what I attempted.

If the $B$ priests are "evenly spaced out", then there should be $B$ "gaps" between the $B$ priests, and so on average there will be $A/B$ knights in each gap. Hence every priest will on average have $2A/B$ knights neighboring it.

But I'm not sure how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your argument can't possibly be right. Suppose that $A = 5$ and $B=2$. Does that mean that every priest has on average $\frac{2A}{B} = 5$ knights sitting directly next to them? There's only $2$ people sitting directly next to the priest, whoever they are, so there can be at most $2$ knights.

Comment: Anyway, start from the probability that both people sitting next to a particular priest are knights.

Comment: To verify the validity of the posted answer, see [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/), which contains a **proof** that the principle may even be applied against **dependent events**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [indicator method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540838) strikes again. Each priest determines whether there is a knight on both sides, which happens with probability $\large\frac{A(A-1)}{(A+B-1)(A+B-2)}$; the expected number of such priests is by linearity of expectation $B$ times this, or $\large\frac{AB(A-1)}{(A+B-1)(A+B-2)}$

Comment: Or similarly, at each place there is a probability of $\frac{B \cdot A(A-1)}{(A+B)(A+B-1)(A+B-2)}$ that at that place, there is a priest with two knights on either side.  Then, there are $A+B$ places to multiply by.